# Error on smbldap-populate: value of naming attribute 'sambaDomainName' is not present

Tags: openldap, samba

Good evening...

I´m studiyng OpenLdap+Samba, testing this article on debian:
http://siddou.hd.free.fr/2013/06/install-sambaopenldap-on-debian-7-wheezy/

And when I put this command:
smbldap-populate i got the error:

```
(S-1-5-21-4222220073-956825759-2129899729)
(using builtin directory structure)

entry dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Users,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Machines,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry ou=Idmap,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist. Updating it...
failed to modify entry: value of naming attribute 'sambaDomainName' is not present in entry at /usr/local/sbin/smbldap-populate line 493.
entry uid=root,ou=Users,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry uid=nobody,ou=Users,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Admins,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Users,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Guests,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Domain Computers,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Administrators,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Account Operators,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Print Operators,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Backup Operators,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.
entry cn=Replicators,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com already exist.

Please provide a password for the domain root:
Changing UNIX and samba passwords for root
New password:
```

It´s not an error but the lines in the middle is not the desired result. So I´m tried to do all again, and again, with no success.

I think it´s related to name of the server or ldap server, so the other files:

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       srvtest.dominio.com  srvtest
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = SMBTEST
        server string = PDC
        netbios name = srvtest
...
 passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://srvtest.dominio.com/"
        ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=dominio,dc=com
        ldap suffix = dc=dominio,dc=com
        ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
        ldap user suffix = ou=Users
        ldap machine suffix = ou=Machines
        ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap
```

/usr/local/etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap.conf

```
masterLDAP="srvtest"
masterPort="389"
slaveLDAP="srvtest"
slavePort="389"
```

/usr/local/etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap_bind.conf

```
masterDN="cn=admin,dc=dominio,dc=com"
masterPw="password"
slaveDN="cn=admin,dc=dominio,dc=com"
slavePw="password"
```

Thnks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I just added the two lines on smbldap.conf:

```
sambaDomain="SMBPAN"
sambaUnixIdPooldn="sambaDomainName=${sambaDomain},${suffix}"
```

It solved the problem.